# Zerodivisionerror in python 2.7

Tags: python, exception, division

I know this question has been asked frequently but I tried to fix it with their suggestion on other discussion but it couldn't help me to fix my problem.
here is my snip code

```
    var_list // it is list value passed over from other function 
    temp_var=0.0
    for for_each in var_list:
        temp_var= temp_var + for_each                           
    # temp_summary = round(float(temp_var) / len(var_list),2)   ----(option 1)                   
    temp_var= temp_var / float(len(var_list)) ------ (option 2)
```

What I'm trying to do is I just want to add all list content from var_list and divided it with its length but it keep popups error saying "zerodivisionerror" even if var_list content is not zero. I tried casting both side variables but still the same. what am I missing here ?

Comment: Your var_list is empty. The code works fine if i pass items in the var_list. Try printing the for_each value in your for-loop. If it doesn't print something, I'm right.

Comment: @Vincent Beltman I do check trust me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps sometimes `var_list` has content, and sometimes it is empty. You could test this theory by putting a print statement right before the error:

```
print('DEBUG: {}'.format(len(var_list)))
```

In any case, you handle the problem by using `try..except`:

```
temp_var = sum(var_list)
try:
    temp_var /= len(var_list)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    # handle the error
    temp_var = 0
```

Comment: I have done checking size and error handling before I post the question, even I have got 300.0 for temp_var that means there are list of content in it but whenever I include the division it pops up the error. do i have to import library?

Comment: Please post your code with the debug print statement, error handling, and post the output and full traceback error message.